# SELECT random but every name should be selected at least once

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in my MySQL query: I have more that 100000 records,
All I want is to select randomly 10 entries where I can see all devices at least once,
Devices names are differents from user to other.
The table has many devices name, the name is in another table where I joined to that table with the device ID
Every user has less than 10 devices so basically I can see all of them in LIMIT 10 but the random function doesn't pick some of them sometimes
I use :

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,signal
FROM my_table
Where name='any_name'
ORDER BY RAND()LIMIt 10
```

This selects 10 entries but sometimes some devices are not selected
Example :

```
+------------+------------+
| Device     | Signal     | 
+------------+------------+
| Router1    | -60        |  
| Router2    | -56        |
| Router3    | -102       |
| Router4    | -125       |
| .......    | ....       |
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: How many devices do you have? If you have more than 10, you can't possibly have every device once with only 10 entries.

Comment: what do you mean by a "selected device" ? Plus, you are not specifying any criteria for your query. (No WHERE clause)

Comment: Suspect you want the name and one of the signal fields for it. DISTINCT refers to the whole row, not just the name field.

Comment: @BrianJ : every user has less than 10 devices

Comment: `GROUP BY name, device` can help you especially combining with `MAX(signal)` or `MIN(signal)`

Comment: @JDev I don't really need a where clause, I just need to select randomly 10 signal, at least one from every device

Comment: so your column name is `name` or `device`? or both?

Comment: with your last edit your question has no sense! :-) `WHERE name='any_name'` will return just `any_name` nothing else

Comment: So you need 10 records no matter what? If there are 9 unique devices one device would be duplicated but with likely different Signals.  If you had 12 unique devices you would get 10 of them with a random signal for each device?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

But make sure you have put your column_name and table_name as your intended.

In additional, try to use this link beside:
http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Good luck.

Comment: this doesnt guarentee that all devices will be selected at least once

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (untested). The logic is to select those device records that their signal is the maximum one for that device.

```
SELECT aa.name, aa.signal
FROM (
    SELECT name, MAX(signal) AS max_signal
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY name
) AS _aa
INNER JOIN my_table AS aa
ON aa.name = _aa.name
WHERE aa.signal = _aa.max_signal
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Please provide us the table structure with some sample data so we will be able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Nasty way of doing it with a sub query on the SELECT:-

```
SELECT b.Device, (SELECT Signal FROM my_table a WHERE a.Device = b.Device ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Device
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 10
) b
```

Comment: this doesn't return 10 rows, this returns 1 row per device

Comment: It selects 10 random devices, and then 1 signal for each of them. Which is what from your description you seemed to require. It you can post some table declares and test data (both the input data and what you want returned for that input data) I can possibly come up with something better